# Zero struct initialization in C

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I noticed that so many times in a modern code (not old legacy one) people keep initializing structs to zero in C with

```
mystruct var;
memset(&var, 0, sizeof(mystruct));
```

or something like that rather than use initializer

```
mystruct var = {0};
```

Is there any advantage of doing so?

Comment: easy way to initialize the struct data with 0.

Comment: People programming in C are often not learning new techniques and keep using old standards without good reasons. There is no advantage using memset.

Comment: There are some who claim that their `memset` code is clearer because it makes the zeroing explicit. These programmers haven't had enough debugging sessions caused by passing the wrong size to `memset`.

Comment: I have recently seen `mystruct var = {}` in some open source project but that's reported not to be ISO compliant when run with `gcc -pedantic`.